# Server 2012 Powershell Check Members of a Group

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I have users and groups in the Users folder of a Windows 2012 Server. I want to check if a user is a member of a group and if not, add to the group. To list the members of a group, I've tried everything including:

get-adgroupmember -identity "cs99group"

which produces the error

get-adgroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'cs99group' under: ...

The following works perfectly

get-adgroupmember -identity "Administrators"

Of course the Administrators group is in the Builtin folder and cs99group is in the Users folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the parameter *-recursive* added?

Does the command *Get-AdGroup* work?
If so, try `Get-AdGroup "cs99group" | get-adgroupmember`

Comment: I get the same error with Get-AdGroup and I have tried the -recursive parameter with no luck. I used the GUI to create the group but am trying to write some scripts to reduce the sys admin work so when I look for the group using the Powershell script, the group isn't found. I must be doing something wrong when I create the group in the GUI but the only real thing I can change is where I create the group.

Comment: Just used new-adgroup "CS99group" -groupscope Global followed by get-adgroup "CS99group" and this worked great. I created the group in the GUI the exact same way. At least this works.